# It is possible to get by query maximum input NUMBER value in column?

Tags: java, database, oracle

For example i have a table with column "example" NUMBER(5,2), if I right - max input value is 999,99.
It's possible get by query value that could be stored in that column? May be any SQL query or by java api?

Comment: Do you mean like `SELECT MAX(example) FROM MyTable` ?

Comment: did you check [max function](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj27781.html)?

Comment: `max(example)` gets the *highest number stored in that column*. From how I understood the question, it's about the highest number that **could be stored** in that column.

Comment: well, as Peter mentioned you can use MAX, but this will use actual table contents... if you want to know that just by the COLUMN data type you will need to look&parse the DESCRIBE of the given table/column ( no library I am aware of now does that )

Comment: @Joachim Sauer understood my question right, sorry for my english guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the values for precision and scale, you should be able to calculate the maximum value like this:

```
int precision = 5;
int scale = 2;
double maxValue = (Math.pow(10, precision) - 1) / Math.pow(10, scale);
```

If you don't know the values for precision and scale, you can query the database metadata:

```
ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getColumns("", "%", "{TABLENAME}", "{COLUMNNAME}");

if(!rs.next()) {
    // unknown table/column
}

int precision = rs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
int scale = rs.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
```

Comment: thank you @jarnbjo but i can't here accept 2 right answers :(, but Evgeniy Dorofeev was first.

Comment: No problem, but you actually asked for the max value, given a specified precision and not how to obtain that precision from the database. If you need to query the database for the precision, it's IMHO better to query the connection metadata (like I did) instead of making an unnecessary "SELECT ... FROM TABLE" as Evgeniy suggests.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    ResultSet rs = ...
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int precision = md.getPrecision(column);
    int scale = md.getScale(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(column_name) as 'Max_number' from table_name
```